# Android Studio 4.0.1 default activity not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-activity, android-manifest

I am using android studio 4.0.1 facing following issue

[image]
[image]

**Tried File -> **Invalidate caches / Restart** this works once. Works for first run only on restart when I try to run it second time it again shows error default activity not found.**

Also tried **Edit Configurations**... set Specified activity strange issue found it says activity not found in manifest

[image]

Here is code from manifest

```
        <activity
        android:name=".config.SplashActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="domain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Branch App Links (optional) -->
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="domain.app.link"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="domain.app.link"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Update: Also tried File -> Sync Project with Gradle files not working.
It is working only once start or restart android studio for second run this issue occurs**

**Update : Tried updating android studio to new version 4.0.2 still facing the same issue**

Comment: have you tried re syncing your gradle

Comment: yes tried no luck

Comment: Post your android manifest

Comment: Please post your manifest file and also your splash activity

Comment: added manifest file code

Comment: is it probably bug android studio? Im using android studio 4.0.1 and often got that error still no luck to resolve it except clone again project from git

Comment: Try to delete `app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @Bek tried still not working

Comment: Please share your full manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Next a list of different actions you can try. **Each entry in the list is a completely different solution independent from each other**:

1. Check your manifest for **merge errors**. Open your manifest and at the bottom select the **Merged Manifest** button. Sometimes such problems are caused by merging conflicts:

[image]

2. Ensure your manifest activity has the next intent filter:

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>`
   ```
3. Edit your "Run / Debug Configurations". Change the "Launch" to "Default Activity". If your activity isn't the default one, then change back to "Specified Activity" but select it from the right menu button "the 3 dots button", and **do not** type manually the activity name.
4. Edit your "Run / Debug configuration". At the bottom of the "general" tab remove the "Gradle-aware Make" entry. Apply it and exit this window. Build your project, then open again "Run / Debug configuration", and add again the "Gradle-aware Make" entry.
5. Delete obsolete Android Studio data folders from previous installations. Under your folder **"C:\Users\<Your user name>\"**, remove any older Android Studio folder from previous installations.
6. "Clean" your project using the option in the "Build" menu, and also use the "Invalidate Caches / Restart" option in Android Studio's File menu.
7. Do not qualify your activity in the manifest tag, so in your case leave it as:

   ```
   android:name=".SplashActivity"
   ```
8. Do the opposite of solution 7, so fully qualify it:

   ```
   android:name="com.my_package.android.config.SplashActivity"
   ```
9. Ensure your activity is defined as **public**:

   ```
   public class SplashActivity extends Activity
   ```
10. This may not make any difference, but remove temporarily your activity's theme tag "android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Splash", just to ensure is not a style related issue which produces an invalid manifest.
11. **Make a backup before proceeding with this solution.** Close your project and delete the project's ".gradle" folder. This one will be autogenerated again next time you open it.
12. Create a new project and import your old project's code into it.
13. Fully reinstall Android Studio, so uninstall and install.

Comment: Have you tried to completely delete Android Studio, including all install setting folders left in your User data folder, and have a new completely fresh install from scratch? Although, before going with such solution, I would try to create a brand new project and re-import the code into it.

Comment: No, I don't want to delete android studio and re-install it

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack. It worked for me several times.

Step 1- Change the launch option to **Nothing**.  [image]

Step 2- Run the app. It will launch the app but no activity will be displayed.

Step 3- Clean the project, uninstall from the device`(optional)`, and again change the configuration to **Default Activity**. And invalidate Cache and Restart.

Comment: Already doing this want to set default activity for launch.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` to the first `<intent-filter>` tag

Comment: Hi Can not share full manifest file do let me know what specifics you want to look at will share

Answer (score 0):

You should give this a try:

- Close Android Studio.
- Delete **C:\Users\username\.AndroidStudio4.x\system\caches** folder.
- Try running the build again.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to close your android studio
Then do this

### deleting :

```
 1 .android

 2 .AndroidStudio

 3 .gradle
```

from C:\Users[your user name]

Start Android studio ( Will take some time to rebuild)

Answer (score 0):

try delete `.idea` folder or use `gradlew build` at Terminal

Answer (score 0):

This same issue happened to me couple of days back and was corrected by using the complete name of my activity including my package name in the manifest file (Strange issue). So in your case use

```
<activity
        android:name="com.my_package.android.config.SplashActivity" //<---this line
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Splash">
```

This process worked for me after 2 tries and after that there is no issue till date.